# Unable to boot openSUSE or SLES12 from plain installation on Gen9 server

Tags: hp-proliant, boot, opensuse, sles

I am installing software on a brand new HP DL120 Gen9 server. This is going to be just a high-performance testing machine.

I wanted to install openSUSE Leap. Intelligent provisioning won't recognize the media. Ok, trying to install by booting from DVD's UEFI. Installation runs fine with default settings. But then the OS won't boot at all. The server will skip from "opensuse-secureboot" to the next boot option.

Tried to install SLES 12 with "Recommended" settings from Intelligent provisioning: media not recognized

Tried to repeat all the installation for SLES12 manually. Won't boot like before.

It seems that the **only** way is to install SLES11 with "Recommended" settings. The system will boot just fine.

I would like to understand why doesn't it work. I wanted to do a custom OS install with custom partition scheme and software packaging, perhaps to export an AutoYast configuration for the next server

Answer (score -2):

Boot the system with kernel command line option `hpsa.hpsa_allow_any=1`

Refer this link for more details: https://www.novell.com/support/kb/doc.php?id=7014067

Comment: Ideally your answer would contain all of the necessary details, **and explanations**, necessary.  Only provide a link for reference, not as the solution; links can change/go stale/dead over time.